# Advance working of /etc/hosts file in ubuntu

Tags: networking, hosts

I have a Java application which is distributed and having a network connection with a NFS share. The application is using DNS to connected to network share.

We wanted to test a network connection failure when the application is running.
So we edited `/etc/hosts` file while the application was running, which simulates a network connection failure. We got the expected outcome.

I just don't understand how editing the `hosts` file with the new (fake) IP address gets updated in real time with the new IP with already running process.

Can someone explain the implementation of this in the OS and how the new IPs are getting mapped to already running process?

Is the OS monitoring the `hosts` file all the time and updating or does it check it when a new connection is created?

Comment: Straight out of the man pages. https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/hosts.5.html     Modifications  to  this  file  normally take effect immediately, except in cases where the
       file is cached by applications.

Comment: Saving the file triggers the re read.

Comment: I found the exact answer i was looking for and explain the implementation https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/526780/why-do-changes-to-etc-hosts-take-effect-immediately

Comment: Because it makes sense that ANY application that is working with the network would read both the /etc/hosts and the /etc/resolv.conf before any communications with the network so that it knows where things are going.

Answer (score 5):

Straight out of the [`hosts` manpage](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/hosts.5.html):

> ```
> Modifications to this file normally take effect immediately, except in
> cases where the file is cached by applications.
> ```

Saving the file triggers the re-read.